# How to change text on tool activated?

Tags: lua, roblox

I was in Roblox again and I wanna make a script where when my tool is activated, it adds 1 to my text label. Example: tool is activated if the text label is zero, change it to one and if it's one, it goes to two and so on. Here's my script:

```
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.cashcount.Text = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.cashcount.Text + 1
end)
```

Comment: When you ask a question, you should include details about what isn't working and/or the error message you're getting.

Comment: Since you don't say what's going wrong, it's a bit hard to guess. But it appears you are  attempting to add an integer to a string. Can't do that in Lua. Maybe try something like `a = tonumber(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.cashcount.Text)`, `a=a+1`, `game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.cashcount.Text = a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your script did not work is because you are trying to add +1 to text, which is like asking "what's 1 plus venus?" creating a variable and then setting the text to the variable works.
Put this LocalScript inside of the tool.

```lua
local cash = 0
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    cash+=1
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.cashcount.Text = tostring(cash)
end)
```

Comment: i already fixed this a different way but i feel like this is easier so thanks

Comment: If it was helpful please mark it correct so others know :)